# swagger docs doesnt reflect object value

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I defined in swagger editor the following object(amountInCurrency):

```
pot:
    type: object
    properties:
      potId:
        type: string
      name:
        type: string
      amount:
        type: number
      status:
        type: string
      lastChangeTimestamp:
        type: string
      amountInCurrency:
        type: object
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/amountInCurrency'
```

and

```
 amountInCurrency:
    type: object
    properties:
     currency:
      type: string
     amount:
      type: number
```

I got in that items currency and amount. however on swagger visualization i see amountInCurrency as an empty map. any idea why?

i would expect to see the currency and amount fields describe in it

[image]

-- edit:
if I change the AmountInCurrency type from object to array I do see the internal docs within the doc

doing this:

```
amountInCurrency:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/amountInCurrency'
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the complete YAML file (or a link to it)?

Comment: it's a bit problematic from secured aspects. perhaps I can past something specific that will help out??

Answer (score 0):

The `amountInCurrency` property  definition does not look right - it mixes `type: object` with an array-specific keyword `items`.

If the `amountInCurrency` property is an array of `amountInCurrency` objects, use `type: array` instead:

```yaml
amountInCurrency:
  type: array   # <-----
  items:
    $ref: '#/definitions/amountInCurrency'
```

If the `amountInCurrency` property is an object (an instance of the `amountInCurrency` object), use `$ref` like so:

```yaml
amountInCurrency:
  $ref: '#/definitions/amountInCurrency'
```